# What's the difference between a service and a store class?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

I came across several classes which all seem to implement similar things. When having 3 application layers (Presentation, Business Logic, Persistence) service or store classes seem to implement the business logic layer. So if I understand correctly this is just a naming convention or is there something I'm missing?

I've seen a `SessionStore` class and a `UserService` but never have I seen a `SessionService` or a `UserStore` (although I'm not certain about the latter).

Comment: `Store` reminds me more of a repository than a business logic class. Anyway it's probably some local naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse `Store` with a business layer class. You will often find `Store` as part of a MVCS pattern (Model-View-Controller-*Store*), an extension of MVC.
It represents storage and is in fact closer to the repository-unitofwork pattern, and is likely to be used by the business layer.

Comment: Ah, so then `Store` and `Repository` are interchangeable (`UserStore`/`UserRepository`)?

Comment: It might mean something slightly different to the developper but as far as I'm aware, apart from the MVCS case, it is not "officially" part of a design pattern as described in either Design Patterns or Code Complete (the two main references in this realm of expertise).

Comment: When talking about a `Repository` class the design pattern applied is the repository pattern. But I've never heard of a store pattern. ;-)